# Declaring an interface which can be iterated over

Tags: c++, iterator

I have created an interface class which defines a Queue for Childpointers.

```
class IChildQueue
{
public:
    IChildQueue(void) {};
    virtual ~IChildQueue(void) {};

public:
    virtual bool add(ChildProcess *oChildProcess) = 0;
    virtual void remove(ChildProcess *oChildProcess) = 0;

    virtual void clear(void) = 0;
    virtual unsigned int size(void) = 0;

    virtual const IChildQueueIterator &begin(void) = 0;  <-- this is the problem
};
```

Now I wanted to add an iterator to the interface so that a client can iterate over the childs without messing with the queue itself.. As my knowledge of C++ is not THAT good, I didn't manage to get this working.

My goal was what I can use the iterator conveniently in a for loop, so it should have autostorage duration and it should act as a proxy to the underlying object. i.E. like this:

```
for(Iterator it = master.begin(); it != it.end(); ++it)
   it->childfunction();   <-- by overloading the -> operator.
```

And No, I don't want to use boost for various reasons.

So far my Iterator looks like this:

```
class IChildQueueIterator
{
public:
    IChildQueueIterator(IChildQueue *pQueue);
    virtual ~IChildQueueIterator() {};

    virtual ChildProcess *operator->() const = 0;
    virtual bool operator==(IChildQueueIterator const &lhs) = 0;
    virtual bool operator!=(IChildQueueIterator const &lhs) = 0;
    virtual ChildProcess &operator++() = 0;
    virtual const ChildProcess operator++(int) = 0;
    virtual bool end(void) = 0;
};
```

I'm not sure if this even possible, but I would at least like to know why, if this is indeed the case.

Comment: Seems ok, but the `begin` function should also be marked `const`. In fact, you should have 2 versions - one `const` that returns a `const` reference, and one non-const that returns a non-const reference.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Careful! You want one `const` that returns a const_iterator and one non-const that returns a non-const_iterator. A const reference to a non-const_iterator does not prevent modification of the value it "points" to: it only prevents modification of the iterator, like ++.

Comment: "My PC crashes, fridge unfreezes and the cows start mooing everytime I try to use Boost".

Comment: That said, don't return iterators as references. It is merely a recipe for pain.

Comment: Oh, yeah, `const_iterator`. :)

Comment: So what should I return instead? As Object? This doesn't work,. because the iterator is also abstract

Comment: @Devolus `IChildQueueIterator` & `IChildQueueConstIterator`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, what does that mean?